# What is the right way to specify headers using axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios, cors, flask-cors

I'm wrestling with cross origin headers while testing my app:

react side:

```
const url = "http://localhost:5000/blog/posts";
const headers = { headers: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" };
axios.post(url, data, headers).then( ...
```

Flask backend `__init__.py`  :

```
...
...
from flask_cors import CORS

def create_app(script_info=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    from project.api.blog import blog_blueprint
    from project.api.auth import auth_blueprint
    CORS(blog_blueprint, resources={'origin': ['http://localhost:3000']})

    app.register_blueprint(blog_blueprint)
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)
    return app
```

the above gives me an exception in the catch block of the `try-catch` statement:
`TypeError: name.toUpperCase is not a function`

using Flask's defaults which means exposing the endpoint to any domain:

```
from project.api.blog import blog_blueprint
from project.api.auth import auth_blueprint
CORS(blog_blueprint)
```

gives me `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/blog/posts. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)`

I've also tried to use a decorator from Flask-CORS:

```
from flask_cors import cross_origin


class BlogPosts(Resource):

    @cross_origin()
    def post(self):
        parser.add_argument('category', type=str)
        parser.add_argument('title', type=str)
        parser.add_argument('post', type=str)
        args = parser.parse_args()
        new_post = Posts(title=args.title, category=args.category, post=args.post)
        db.session.add(new_post)
        db.session.commit()
        return {'status': 'success', 'message': 'post added'}, 201
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, I fixed my problem by refactoring my code into function-based view:

```
CORS(blog_blueprint)

@blog_blueprint.route('/posts', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@cross_origin()
def blog_posts():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_data = request.get_json()
        category = post_data.get('category')
        title = post_data.get('title')
        post = post_data.get('post')
        new_post = Posts(title=title, category=category, post=post)
        db.session.add(new_post)
        db.session.commit()
        return {'status': 'success', 'message': 'post added'}, 201
    return {'status': 'success', 'message': [post.to_json() for post in Posts.query.filter_by(category=category)]}, 200
```

I'm not very happy with this because Flask's CORS library should work same regardless if I'm using class-based or function-based view for handling APIs.